# LINQ and Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have WPF .NET FW4 application with linq and SQL CE 4.0. Randomly on customer's notebook I recieving this error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I already know, that important is Inner exception (with stack trace):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at lambda_method(Closure )

Code block:

```
private void LoadCustomersDetail(CustomersView cw)
    {
        Persons customer = db.Persons.Where(c => c.Person_id == cw.Customer_id).FirstOrDefault();
        reg = new RegistrationWindow(db, customer, false);
        reg.ShowDialog();
        if (reg.DialogResult.Value)
        {
            if (!onlyDebtors)
                LoadCustomers();
            else
                LoadDebtors();
        }
    }
```

Stack trace for original exception:

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetKeyFromPredicate(MetaType type, Dictionary`2 keys, Expression mex, Expression vex)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetKeysFromPredicate(MetaType type, Dictionary`2 keys, Expression expr)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetKeyValues(MetaType type, LambdaExpression predicate)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetCachedResult(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ProjectName.Core.ViewWindow.LoadCustomersDetail(CustomersView cw)
   at ProjectName.Core.ViewWindow.dataGridCustomersList_MouseDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.HandleDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: a null customer would be my first thing to test for - does your RegistrationWindow constructor handle that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception seems to concern the `Where`-expression, so either `c` or `cw` is null. I would recommend an argument check at the beginning of the method (throw `ArgumentNullException` if `cw == null`).
Also make sure the `Persons` collection contains no null values (if that is even possible).

Comment: I tried to set cw to null, and now original exception is Object reference not set..., but with different stack trace and it is happing in next steps in RegistrationWindow constructor. If you check stack trace, you will see that it fails on FirstOrDefault() method calling.

Comment: Ah sorry I tried this: Persons customer = db.Persons.Where(c => c.Person_id == NULL).FirstOrDefault(); And it is not same like:    cw = null;
Persons customer = db.Persons.Where(c => c.Person_id == cw.Customer_id).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here `cw.Customer_id`. your `cw` is `null`.