# Exception occured on query when i Edit or Delete row from wpf datagrid using LINQ to SQL

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF and C#.

I am trying CRUD operations on WPF Datagrid. My datagrid shown records from two table that are linked with foreign key reference.

But the problem occurs when I edit a cell data and click on submit button the following message is displayed by exception.

> ERROR:"Excetpion has thrown by the target on invocation" and it point
>   me on linq to sql query that i have written in edit code.

Same problem occurs when I perform Delete operation.

```
    private void LoadDataGrid()
    {

        DataClassesDataContext dataContext = new DataClassesDataContext();

        var results = from b in dataContext.iBankNames
                      join acc in dataContext.iBankAccountNos on b.BankID equals acc.BankId
                      orderby b.Name ascending
                      select new
                      {
                          BankID = b.BankID,
                          BankName = b.Name,
                          BankAccNo = acc.BankAccNo,
                          BranchName = acc.Branch
                      };

        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = results;

    }
```

and here is my XML Code of wpf.

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" x:Uid="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   SelectionMode="Single" 
                AlternationCount="2"

              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bank ID" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding BankID,Mode=OneWay}"
                                />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

           <!----HERE ARE SOME MORE COLOUMNS----->


            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit Row">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Edit" Click="EditButton_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete Row">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteButton_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is Edit code:

```
         private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            DataClassesDataContext dataContextEdit = new DataClassesDataContext();
            iBankName bankRow = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as iBankName;
            //string m = customerRow.CustomerID;
            iBankName bank = (from p in dataContextEdit.iBankNames
                                 where p.BankID == bankRow.BankID
                                 select p).Single();

            bank.Name = bankRow.Name;

            iBankAccountNo banAccRow = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as iBankAccountNo;

            iBankAccountNo bankAccNo = (from p in dataContextEdit.iBankAccountNos
                                            where p.BankAccNo == banAccRow.BankAccNo
                                            select p).Single();

            bankAccNo.BankAccNo = banAccRow.BankAccNo;
            bankAccNo.Branch = banAccRow.Branch;

            dataContextEdit.SubmitChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Row Updated Successfully.");

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
           // return;
        }
    }
```

I am using VS 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Express.

Comment: my guess, your problem is in the sql operation (could be: changing primary key, or error foreign key constrait, etc). Try to simulate what your linq was trying to do directly using sql statement in SSMS.

Comment: I have done in SSMS but found not error. Every thing is fine in foreign key constraints.

Comment: you need to specify more detailed error message, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809530/linq-and-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation) may be. And which linq was causing error, the one when you assign bank variable or bankAccNo varibale?

Comment: hmm.. possible error source i can think of: Single() will throw error if no data matched by your query, use SingleOrDefault() to avoid this error.

Comment: @har07 thanks. error occured on bank variable. But i don't know how to print whole stack error. I have used SigleOrDefault() but it also didn't work. When i appliend ex.InnerException.Message() on cathc exception it shows "Object reference not set to instance of object".

Comment: I would recommend to check if bankRow.BankID is null, or is there any iBankName having BankID = null. Maybe comparing null value trigger error

Comment: nah, you said that. Something must be null. Maybe bankRow?

Comment: I have checked all the bank rows but there is no column having null value exist either parent or foreign key column. In backend I have created Linq to Sql where i have map all the tables in O/R designer of LINQ to SQL. every thing go na fine it works on other db's but in this db it give error.

Comment: oH one thing that i forget to mention that I have set BankAccNo type as BigInteger. I think error occured when i make comparison to bank accountNo and bankRow accountNo. Is it true that we can't make comparison of such type values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I think it is properly work....

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        DataClassesDataContext dataContextEdit = new DataClassesDataContext();
                   object item = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem;

        string m = (MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[cellNumber].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text
        iBankName bank = (from p in dataContextEdit.iBankNames
                             where p.BankID == m
                             select p).Single();

        bank.Name = (MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[ColumnNumber].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text

        //iBankAccountNo banAccRow = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as iBankAccountNo;

//similarly another object create and access item
object item = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        iBankAccountNo bankAccNo = (from p in dataContextEdit.iBankAccountNos
                                        where p.BankAccNo == banAccRow.BankAccNo
                                        select p).Single();

        bankAccNo.BankAccNo = (MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[columnNumber].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text
        bankAccNo.Branch = (MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[columnNumber].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text

        dataContextEdit.SubmitChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Row Updated Successfully.");

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
       // return;
    }
}
```